# Get star rating from number using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, render, raty

Here I have code to convert number(rating) into stars using http://wbotelhos.com/raty, http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/jquery.raty.min.js

I create an jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3SXKe/4/

```
// mocking your supposed "place" variable
var place = { name: "James Cook Hotel Grand Chancellor", rating: "3.6",
    photos: [{ getUrl: function () { return "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-T0_fJX5zza0/UdSnOaucZvI/AAAAAAAAAFc/gQhK3IbHJfY/w50-h50-s0/Small%2BLogo.png" } }]
}

var photo = place.photos[0].getUrl({
    'maxWidth': 50,
    'maxHeight': 50
});

var elemenatDiv = $('<div>').addClass('elemenat');
var draggableDiv = $('<div>').addClass('draggable');
var logo = $('<img>').css({'margin-left': '3px', 'margin-top': '5px'})
                     .attr('src', photo).attr('width', 46).attr('height', 42)
var sideClick = $("<a>").addClass('side_click').attr('href', '#')
                        .text(place.name + place.rating);
var elementnameDiv = $('<div>').addClass('elementname');
var star = $('#star').raty({ score: place.rating });

elemenatDiv.append(draggableDiv.append(logo));
elemenatDiv.append(elementnameDiv.append(sideClick).append(star));

$("#side_bar").append(elemenatDiv);

$(sideClick).on("click", function () {
    markers[i].modalWindow_.getDetails(markers[i].place_);
});
```

and I use first:     `var star = $('#star').raty({ score: place.rating });` and after that append     `elemenatDiv.append(elementnameDiv.append(sideClick).append(star));`

but star rating won't to show when render html code?

I try different solution but I dont know where is error?

Comment: I also add: var star = $('#star').raty({ score: place.rating, path: 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img' }); but again dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
var star = $('#star').raty({ score: place.rating });
```

You are trying to select a DOM element by ID (`#star`), but there is no element in the DOM.

You need to an inject a DIV with an ID of `star` into the DOM.

Comment: Do you maybe know why I can use this code into google maps api code?